# How to append next line to previous line until input string match

Tags: shell

Any hint on how to read the below file line by line until given input string match

```
content1 = {
{
n no of lines
}
}
content2 = {
{
n no of lines
}
}
content3 = {
{
n no of lines
}
}
```

and write output as below in each block in one line do remember n means is random number lines not constant number.

```
Content1 = { n no of lines }
Content2 = { n no of lines }
Content3 = { n no of lines }
```

Comment: What's the input string? What does it match? How are the lines delimited after joining them? What happens to the inner braces?

Comment: Input strings like content1, content2... and we need braces too in output.